# How can I Run a select block of Python code in Vim?

Tags: python, vim

for example, I have two functions one for add and another for subtraction if I want to run only the add function how can I do that in vim?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bvim%5D+run+block

Comment: https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun